# How to slow down the web

Tags: debian, http-proxy, www

You may think that your internet connection is anyway too slow, but here I have the opposite problem.

I am not very good at concentration, and I believe that part of the problem is the ease with which which one can get all the interesting stuff from the Web. It can be quite distracting, and I am certainly not the first one to notice it.

Switching the internet connection off is one possible solution, but often I need at least *some* connectivity. An example is reading and writing email. So I thought that a slow web connection might be another compromise. (There is research that the texts written in a difficult typeface is read with more concentration than normal text. This is another reason why I think that making the web more difficult to access might be good for concentration.)

So what do I think of?

- I would like to be able to set the maximal speed of the HTTP connections to any value I like, because I do not yet know which speed (if any) is good.
- Other connections, like emails, should not be affected.
- Bonus points if it is also possible to exempt specific web addresses - such that dowmloading Debian packages via HTTP is still fast.
- If possible, it should require only modifications of my own machine.

A possible solution could involve a proxy server, with the right configuration.

Do you know a solution? Or even better, had you already the same problem and solved it?

Comment: I really think that a squid proxy setup with delaybuckets is the way to go, then point your browser to the proxy and let those bits slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called **wondershaper**
[here](http://www.ubuntu-unleashed.com/2008/05/howto-limit-uploaddownload-speeds-and.html) it's well explained.

Regards!

Comment: wondershaper is to provide less latency and more responsiveness, not to limit network speed. In a nutshell, it prioritize some protocols/connections over others.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO](http://lartc.org/howto/).  There's a lot there, and (unsurprisingly) most of it is aimed at increasing speeds, but there's a fair bit about throttling outbound traffic that could be re-purposed for your requirements.

There should be enough in it to show you how you can use different queuing disciplines for HTTP/HTTPS and other (non-Web) traffic, and provide exceptions for specific servers (though note that you'll have to do that by address rather than by DNS name, as packet filtering is at too low a level).